# Python script to configure an XBee module fails on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, configuration, raspberry-pi, xbee

I have a python script that I want to use to configure some XBee modules. It works perfectly find when connect to a computer via an [xbee development board](http://microframework.dk/post/XBee-RF-module-specifications.aspx), but fails when connect to a raspberry pi via the slice of pi board.

I have narrowed down the problem to it failing to enter the command mode, after sending the +++ the xbee never sends the OK message. Here is the relevant code:

```
...
CC = '+'
GT = '1.1' # Tried different values here
...

def startCommandMode(self):
    self.emptyBuffer() # Tried with and without this line
    sleep(self.GT) # Tried with and without this line
    self.ser.write(self.CC + self.CC + self.CC)
    sleep(self.GT)
    return self.getReply() == 'OK'

...

def getReply(self):
    count = 0
    reply = ''
    while True:
        char = self.ser.read()
        if char == '\r':
            break
        if len(char) == 0:
            return None
        reply += char

    return reply
```

The full source is available on [github](https://github.com/james147/xbee-config/blob/master/xbee-config.py) if needed.

I know it is not a problem with the xbee module, the raspberry pi or the slice of pi board as it works perfectly fine if I try it manually using "picocom -lc /dev/ttyAMA0".

Comment: Can you confirm that `sleep()` is really sleeping for 1.1 seconds?

Comment: The default guard time on the xbee modules is 1 second and you have to make sure no reads happen before this. I have tried various values up to about 5 seconds with no success, so a little error in the timing is acceptable. And on my desktop all of these values work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Are you getting anything in response?
- Have you enabled flow-control on the XBee?  Make sure `D6` and `D7` are set to 0 since the Raspberry Pi serial port doesn't have flow control.
- Is the Python code configured for flow control?  It might be waiting for a CTS signal that is never asserted.
- Can you try using the XBee Development Board on the Raspberry Pi's USB port?

Answer (score 0):

Use  the following:

```
....
if args.common:
    args.at = ['ID', 'CH', 'MY', 'DL', 'DH', 'AP'] + args.at
xbee = XBee(args.port, args.baud);
sleep(2)
xbee.CC = args.CC
xbee.GT = args.GT
....
....
```

IMHO I thick Rpi need more time to initialize serial port, thats why I am using this delay
. Also is applicable for transparent mode so add a delay after port init.

I hope this will Ok for you. For me it is solved.

BR.
Manel.